# Will Modifying a Wardrobe Box for Temporary Use/Moving ruin its structural integrity?

Tags: storage

I have some time between leases that I'll be living in a temporary location and I picked up a wardrobe box (a large box with a cross-bar for hanging clothes).  I'd like to try to store most of my wardrobe in it, including shoes and non-hanging clothing items, for a few weeks and while moving.  There's a lot of space in the bottom of the box underneath the hanging clothes, but as it's pretty deep it's hard to access.  I was thinking about cutting a flap near the base that I would tape shut while moving, but leave untaped during the few weeks I need access to the clothes.  Is this likely to ruin the box's structural integrity?

(Let me know if this is off-topic; I really wasn't sure)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure this is on topic, but I'll try.  I assume you mean one of these:[image]

If you want to cut a hole in it, you'll want to cut it in the "front" and make sure you don't go all the way across it from left to right.  Alternatively, you can just use a boxcutter or utility knife to make the seam deeper for the front flap, so you can just reach in directly.  I know what you mean about the bottom being inaccessible, we had the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's the type of box I meant.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If the extra cuts seem to have weakened the box too much after you tape it closed, you can tape wide cardboard strips folded 90 degrees over the 'door' joints to reinforce the area.